# Pregreplace youtube embed with an image

Tags: wordpress, youtube, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm attempting to do something very odd, and I'm having some luck, but am running in to some snags. I have basically finished the first bit of it, now I just need to translate it across the board. This has to do with WordPress, but it is a general concept question as apposed to a WP specific, so I decided to ask it here.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is parse through a variable, and replace a bit of code with something else, if it exists (for WP users, I'm attempting to parse through the_content(), a replace a bit based on some conditions).

I am parsing over a variable called `$content`. Somewhere within `$content` will be a standard YouTube emebed code `<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxx" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315"></iframe>` etc. What I am aiming to do, is grab the xxxxxx value, then replace the whole `<iframe>` with an `<img>` anchor.

I have the regex to grab the YouTube video id, and can echo the image no problem. I used:

```
if (preg_match('(/embed/([a-z0-9A-Z]+))', $content, $output) > 0) {
        echo("<img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/".$output[1]."/0.jpg' alt=' ' />");
    }
```

Which returns the thumbnail of the YouTube video found in `$content`. I am having trouble translating this regex in to a `preg_replace` so that I can change the `<iframe>` in to an `<img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/xxxxxxxxx/0.jpg />` instead. Is this possible?

I would love if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Tre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate doing this so quickly. But, I seem to have solved my issue already.

Coming on here and typing it out and clearing my mind seems to help here and there.

I was able to accomplish it with this code (which I'm sure is ugly):

```
        $the_id = preg_match('(/embed/([a-z0-9A-Z]+))', $content, $output);
        $replacement = "<img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/".$output[1]."/0.jpg' alt=' ' />";

        $content = preg_replace("/<iframe.*?<\/iframe>/si", $replacement, $content);
        echo $content;
```